# BigQuery Schema Update while copying data from other tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have table1 which has lots of nested columns. And table2 has some additional columns which may have nested columns. I'm using golang client library.

Is there any way to update the schema while copying from one table to another table..?

Sample Code :

```
dataset := client.Dataset("test")
copier=dataset.Table(table1).CopierFrom(dataset.Table(table2))
copier.WriteDisposition = bigquery.WriteAppend
copier.CreateDisposition = bigquery.CreateIfNeeded
job, err = copier.Run(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error while run :", err)
    }
    status, err = job.Wait(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error in wait :", err)
    }
    if err := status.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error in status :", err)
    }
```

Comment: Hi there. Can you provide more information about your problem and what it is exactly you're trying to achieve? There's not a lot of info to go off here TBH.

Comment: Hi @Graham Polley, sample code added for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some background first: 
I created 2 Tables under the data collection `test` as following: 
`1` Schema: name (String), age (Integer)

```
"Varun", 19
"Raja", 27
```

`2` Schema pet_name (String), type (String)

```
"jimmy", "dog"
"ramesh", "cat"
```

Note that the two relations have different schemas.
Here I am copying the contents of data table `2` into `1`. The `bigquery.WriteAppend` tells the query engine to append results of table `2` into `1`.

```golang
test := client.Dataset("test")
copier := test.Table("1").CopierFrom(test.Table("2"))
copier.WriteDisposition = bigquery.WriteAppend
if _, err := copier.Run(ctx); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
query := client.Query("SELECT * FROM `test.1`;")
results, err := query.Read(ctx)
if err != nil {
   log.Fatalln(err)
}
for {
    row := make(map[string]bigquery.Value)
    err := results.Next(&row)
    if err == iterator.Done {
        return
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(row)
}
```

**Nothing happens** and the result is:

```
map[age:19 name:Varun]
map[name:Raja age:27]
```

Table `1`, the destination is unchanged.
What if source and destination had the same schemas in the copy?
For example:

```golang
copier := test.Table("1").CopierFrom(test.Table("1"))
```

Then the copy succeeds! Add table `1` has twice the rows that initially had.

```
map[name:Varun age:19]
map[age:27 name:Raja]
map[name:Varun age:19]
map[name:Raja age:27]
```

But what if we somehow wanted to **combine tables** even **with different schemas**?

Well first you need a GCP Billing account as your are technically doing Data Manipulations (DML). You can get $300 free credit.

Then the following will work

```golang
query := client.Query("SELECT * FROM `test.2`;")
query.SchemaUpdateOptions = []string{"ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION", "ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION"}
query.CreateDisposition = bigquery.CreateIfNeeded
query.WriteDisposition = bigquery.WriteAppend
query.QueryConfig.Dst = client.Dataset("test").Table("1")
results, err := query.Read(ctx)
```

And the result is

```
map[pet_name:<nil> type:<nil> name:Varun age:19]
map[name:Raja age:27 pet_name:<nil> type:<nil>]
map[pet_name:ramesh type:cat name:<nil> age:<nil>]
map[pet_name:jimmy type:dog name:<nil> age:<nil>]
```

**EDIT**

Instead of `query.Read()` you can use `query.Run()` if you just want to run the query and not fetch results back, as show below:

```golang
if _, err := query.Run(ctx); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

Important things to note:

- We have set `query.SchemaUpdateOptions` to include `ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION` which will allow for the resulting table to have columns not originally present.
- We have set `query.WriteDisposition` to `bigquery.WriteAppend` for data to be appended.
- We have set `query.QueryConfig.Dst` to `client.Dataset("test").Table("1")` which means the result of the query will be uploaded to `1`.
- Values that are not in both tables but in just one are *nullified* or set to `nil` in Golang sense.

This *hack* will give you the same results as combining two tables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this also. The query will bring the data to our environment. Instead of that I need a simple statement to be done by bigquery end.

Comment: @ArulRulzz can you clarify as to how the approach done here will bring data to your environment? There is no data saved to your local machine. Everything is done on GCP.

Comment: Updated to your requirements @ArulRulzz

Comment: This helps a lot. Thanks